# New to jQuery trying to use $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

So after a day spent on skim reading w3schools/jQuery docs/Through dozens of examples and watching a few youtube videos just to learn how to get external json data i finally gave up and decided to ask here why doesn't this work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").onClick(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/netuetamundis?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(result){
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $("div").append("<b>" + key.name + "</b>");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button>Get Json Data</button>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And also is there a way to do this from regular javascript without any libraries, I was googling this, but everythin I found pretty much led to $.getJSON

Comment: chnage to `$("button").onClick` to `$("button").click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes replace `onCllick` with `click` and key.name would not work, use key and value separately.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUuNG/) for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/netuetamundis?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(result){
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $("div").append("<b>" +key+"--"+value +"</b><br/>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, you can use `click()` function instead of `onClick()`.

Change to

```
$("button").onClick(function(){
```

to

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

Comment: Nothing, the button just stays unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

1. onClick is not a jQuery function, use `.click`, http://api.jquery.com/click/,
2. $.ajax will do what you want if you specify the datatype. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

do something like this

```
$('button').click(function(e){
   $.ajax({
     url: "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/netuetamundis?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a",
     success: function(data){
       $.each(data, function(key, val){
            $("div").append("<b>" + key + "</b>");
       })
     }
   })
}
```

Comment: The question specified `$.getJSON`, and besides, convenience methods are nice because they instantly communicate the intent: "I am trying to retrieve JSON from this URL", as opposed to having to spend brain cycles looking for the data type trying to decide what data type is expected from that URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native ajax request object without any librearies like

```
<button onclick="load()">Get Json Data</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

then

```
function load() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var result = JSON.parse(text);

            var array = [];
            for (var key in result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    array.push("<b>" + key + "--" + result[key] + "</b><br/>")
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = array.join('')
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/netuetamundis?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b6XVe/)

Note: For supporting older browsers which does not support [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON), you will have to include a polyfil library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)